# Google ReCaptcha v2 bad php script

Tags: php, recaptcha

I'm trying to make Login Panel, all is working fine without ReCaptcha. But when I verify that I am not a robot and log in, it shows that there is an incorrect ReCaptcha.

```
<?php
 require_once('includes/config.php');
if( $user->is_logged_in() ){ header('Location: index.php'); exit(); }
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if (!isset($_POST['username'])) $error[] = "No username.";
    if (!isset($_POST['password'])) $error[] = "Type pass.";
    if(!$captcha){
        echo 'Check ReCaptcha';
        exit;
}
    $secretKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip);
    $responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
if(intval($responseKeys["success"]) !== 1) {
    echo 'Check ReCaptcha';
    exit;
} else {
$username = $_POST['username'];
if ( $user->isValidUsername($username)){
        if (!isset($_POST['password'])){
            $error[] = 'Type pass';
        }
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if($user->login($username,$password)){

            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header('Location: memberpage.php');
            exit;

        } else {
            $error[] = 'Wrong pass.';
        }
    }else{
        $error[] = 'Wrong pass.';
    }
}

}
```

Comment: you have not set $captcha. It should be something like $captcha = $_POST['captcha'] where 'captcha' is name of input where you insert captcha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check for captcha is empty or not and check is verify or not:

```
$secretKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$captcha  = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

if($captcha == null) {
    echo 'Check ReCaptcha';
    exit;
}
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" . $secretKey . "&response=" . $captcha . "&remoteip=" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']), true);

if ($response['success'] != true) {
    echo 'captcha is wrong!';
    exit;
}
```